# Hibernate: Inheritance strategy, and annotations when persist abstract collections bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, associations

I am struggling with the right combination of inheritance strategy, and associations annotations when trying to persist abstract collections bidirectional with Hibernate. 
All attempts I made so far fail, most with the complaint that @ManyToOne references an unknown identity.

Given the below example, the questions I have are

- what is the best to maintain hibernate inheritence strategy for the
  below structure?
- which row id generation fits the inheritence strategy?
- how to annotate each of the classes (e.g. @Entity, @MappedSuperclass)?
- how to annotate the methods or field definitions (e.g. @ManyToOne, @OneToMany?

Since my code is embedded in a bigger structure and each class is rather big, here is a mock about cars - which is still big. Some relations I would model differently if I would really model cars, but this mock hopefully describes the basic problem in a more digestable form, without all the ballast from my real code.

The relations look  like this:

[image: <UML class diagram>]

the related java code looks like this:

```
package persistence;

public abstract class MechanicalObject {

    private int weight;

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public abstract void someMethod();
}



package persistence;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class Car extends MechanicalObject {

    protected List<Engine> potentialEngines;    // references to something that also extends MechanicalObject
    protected List<Driver> potentialDrivers;    // references to something that does not extend MechanicalObject

    public List<Engine> getPotentialEngines() {
        return potentialEngines;
    }

    public void setPotentialEngines(List<Engine> potentialEngines) {
        this.potentialEngines = potentialEngines;
    }

    public List<Driver> getPotentialDrivers() {
        return potentialDrivers;
    }

    public void setPotentialDrivers(List<Driver> potentialDrivers) {
        this.potentialDrivers = potentialDrivers;
    }
}



package persistence;

public abstract class Engine extends MechanicalObject {

    private int driveRPM;
    private Car parent;     // bidirectional reference

    public int getDriveRPM() {
        return driveRPM;
    }

    public void setDriveRPM(int driveRPM) {
        this.driveRPM = driveRPM;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // do something
    }

    public abstract void anotherMethod();

}



package persistence;


public class Driver {

    // db row id
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String licenceType;
    private Car parent;     // bidirectional reference


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLicenceType() {
        return licenceType;
    }

    public void setLicenceType(String licenceType) {
        this.licenceType = licenceType;
    }

    public Car getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Car parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}



package persistence;

public class CombustionEngine extends Engine {

    // db row id
    private long id;

    private int cylinderCapacity;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCylinderCapacity() {
        return cylinderCapacity;
    }

    public void setCylinderCapacity(int cylinderCapacity) {
        this.cylinderCapacity = cylinderCapacity;
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {
        // do something differently
    }
}



package persistence;

public class ElectroEngine extends Engine {

    // db row id
    private long id;

    private int nominalVoltage;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getNominalVoltage() {
        return nominalVoltage;
    }

    public void setNominalVoltage(int nominalVoltage) {
        this.nominalVoltage = nominalVoltage;
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}



package persistence;

public class TeslaModelX extends Car {

    private long id;

    private String licenceNumber;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLicenceNumber() {
        return licenceNumber;
    }

    public void setLicenceNumber(String licenceNumber) {
        this.licenceNumber = licenceNumber;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // do something differently
    }

}



package persistence;

public class VWBeetle extends Car {

    private long id;

    private String serialNumber;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // do something differently
    }
}
```

I would be greatful for any help. Links to web pages that explain the solution are also welcome, as I couldn't find any that handeled this subject completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the best to maintain hibernate inheritence strategy for the below structure?

That depends on what the rest of your model looks like. The easiest to use strategy would be single-table but if the subclasses differ too much a joined-table strategy or table-per-class strategy might be better. Just read up on those and pick one you're comfortable with. Note, however, that it's hard to change inheritance strategy further down the hierarchy - if it's possible at all (probably depends on the JPA provider).

> which row id generation fits the inheritence strategy?

I'd say those are independent as Hibernate should handle that for you. Just pick an id generation strategy that fits your needs. What you'd probably need though is a discriminator column to let Hibernate identify the entity class each row represents.

> how to annotate each of the classes (e.g. @Entity, @MappedSuperclass)?

That depends on your needs but I'd assume that `Car` and `Engine` aren't that related so they'd be entities while `MechanicalObject` could be a mapped superclass. Of course, if you want some other entity to reference any `MechanicalObject` you might have to make it an entity as well, use a different mapping approach or rethink your requirements/model.

> how to annotate the methods or field definitions (e.g. @ManyToOne, @OneToMany?

Do as needed and read up on the annotations. Just keep in mind that one side needs to be the owner of the relation, i.e. only changes to that side are persisted on the database. If you don't do that you risk corrupting your model and confusing the JPA provider. The easiest way to do that on bidirectional 1-n relations would be to add `mappedBy="..."` to the 1-side, i.e. to `@OneToMany`.

As an example, your `Car-Driver` relation could look like this:

```
class Car extends MechanicalObject {
  @OneToMany( mappedBy="parent" )
  protected List<Driver> potentialDrivers; 
}

class Driver {
  @ManyToOne
  protected Car parent; //I'd use a better name here
}
```